# How to create string with line breaks in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a text :

> What would I do without your smart mouth?
>   Drawing me in, and you kicking me out
>   You've got my head spinning, no kidding, I can't pin you down
>   What's going on in that beautiful mind
>   I'm on your magical mystery ride
>   And I'm so dizzy, don't know what hit me, but I'll be alright

...now I want to create a string with this text. For example in Python:

```
string = " What would I do without your smart mouth?
Drawing me in, and you kicking me out
You've got my head spinning, no kidding, I can't pin you down
What's going on in that beautiful mind
I'm on your magical mystery ride
And I'm so dizzy, don't know what hit me, but I'll be alright "
```

But Python didn't consider this as string as it contain line breaks. How can I make this text as a string?

Comment: **Creating Multiline String** Include multiline strings inside triple quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using triple-quotes

You can use the triple-quotes (`"""` or `'''`) to assign a string with line breaks:

```
string = """What would I do without your smart mouth?
Drawing me in, and you kicking me out
You've got my head spinning, no kidding, I can't pin you down
What's going on in that beautiful mind
I'm on your magical mystery ride
And I'm so dizzy, don't know what hit me, but I'll be alright"""
```

As explained by [**the documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html):

> String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using triple-quotes: `"""..."""` or `'''...'''`. End of lines are automatically included in the string [...]

## Using `\n`

You can also explicitly use the newline character (`\n`) inside your string to create line breaks:

```
string = "What would I do without your smart mouth?\nDrawing me in, and you kicking me out\nYou've got my head spinning, no kidding, I can't pin you down\nWhat's going on in that beautiful mind\nI'm on your magical mystery ride\nAnd I'm so dizzy, don't know what hit me, but I'll be alright"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Through the following code lines:

```
value = '''
    String
    String
    String
    '''
```

---

```
value = """
    String
    String
    String
    """
```

---

```
value = 'String\nString\nString'
```

---

```
value = "String\nString\nString"
```

---

### The output is same with above code lines:

```
>>> print value
String
String
String
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to triple-quote it:

```
string = '''What would I do without your smart mouth?
Drawing me in, and you kicking me out
You've got my head spinning, no kidding, I can't pin you down
What's going on in that beautiful mind
I'm on your magical mystery ride
And I'm so dizzy, don't know what hit me, but I'll be alright'''
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? (i ask like this coz you say that this is the easiest way,that means there may exists some other ways to do it ) btw i'm a mathematician..lol